# Should constructors do the computation for once needed long running tasks?

Tags: java, constructor

The following example is tailor made to make my doubts clear.

EG: WAP, with a method `getAllWordsStartingInputChar` to return the frequency of a word in the dictionary. The dictionary in form of a hashmap would be provided to the constructor.

Now, before `getAllWordsStartingInputChar` is called for the first time, I need to create another map of `char->list of words begining with that char`

Where should this map be created ?

1. In the constructor ?
2. Lazy initialization ?
3. Anything else ?

Please try to avoid being specific about my example, the idea i am trying to convey is 'some computation that needs to be done, whose results would be stored and used over and over again'.
Where should such computation be done.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. How can there be multiple entries of a word, if it is a `Map`? If the words are values, what are the keys. How do you call `getFrequency`, with a word to count? And what is a WAP?

Comment: Almost always the answer to such questions is "it depends." If you are going to create 1,000 of these objects and only invoke getFrequency() on 5 of them, lazy might be best. Which is more important for your performance, memory footprint or response time of the getFrequency() call? Should getFrequency() be made async, with a callback? These things are extremely situation-depdendent.

Comment: You can create it in all the above.  There is not enough information to give a conclusive answer.  I would consider storing it in a static final field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please try to avoid being specific about my example

Thats's no problem, because I cannot be *too specific* about this example when the example itself is not very specific (just kidding a little).

> Seriosly, there is no problem to initialize a HashMap in the constructor

as long as you don't start a thread which uses these variables or  call a method which do that or, also evil, call a overridable method in the constructor. Probably I forgot something.

> Strategie of creation

If your Map `list of words beginning with that char` is used in each case, which means, there is no case in which you don't need the map, than you should create it during construction.

If these map is used very seldom, chose lazy initiaization, e.g. at the first call of a getter.

That is just my opinion without knowing very much about your needs.

Answer (score 1):

> Where should this map be created ?
>
> 1) In the constructor ?

Possibly.

> 2) Lazy initialization ?

Possibly.

> 3) Anything else ?

Probably not.

In purely performance terms, the choice between 1) and 2) depends on the probability that the constructed object *won't* use the second map.  You need to balance the cost of the laziness (extra tests each time the map is used) versus the cost of creating the map unnecessarily.

The only "anything else" that I can think of is creating the second map each time that you use it.  That only makes sense from a performance perspective if the map is only ever used zero or one time.

---

> Where should such computation be done.

From a performance perspective, that's probably not relevant.  From a design perspective ... you can make make a variety of arguments about where the code belongs.  It is a matter of personal taste (IMO).

But looking back at the above comparison of 1) versus 2), the other observation is that this smells of "premature optimization", and premature optimization is often a complete waste of time.  For more on that topic, read this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/172.

If you have perfect information of how the costs will work out in practice, then the optimization is just "maths".  But in practice, you rarely have enough information, and the mathematics is frequently too complicated.  And general "rule of thumb" answers are not going to be reliable.  Hence, each situation needs to be optimized on its merits ... based on real performance measurement.  (If the effort is warranted!)